# calculate the Integer solutions of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How does anyone calculate the "integer solutions" of an equation in this example:

$$
x(x+1) + 62 = y^2
$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*%28x%2B1%29%2B62%3Dy%5E2

here the Integer solutions are :
$x = -62$, $y= 62$
$x = -2$, $y= 8$
$x = 1$, $y= 8$
$x = 61$, $y= 62$

How do they get $8$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

The equation can be written as
$$(2x+1)^2-(2y)^2=-247 \implies (2x+1-2y)(2x+1+2y)=-247.$$
Note that $247=13 \cdot 19$. So factor pairs are $(1,247), \, (13,19)$.

Comment: how do they got 8 in the posted example ?

Comment: @Billysenders $2x+1-2y=-13$ and $2x+1+2y=19$ will give $x=1$ and $y=8$ and $2x+1-2y=-19$ and $2x+1+2y=13$ will give $x=-2$ and $y=8$.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply it by 4: $$4x^2+4x+248=4y^2$$ so $$(2x+1)^2+247 = 4y^2$$ and thus $$4y^2-(2x+1)^2=247$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: thanks, still don't know how they got 8 in the posted example !